# Running PL SQL script in Jenkins

Tags: oracle, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, sqlplus

I am able to download code from clear case using Jenkins. 
Now I am trying to run a SQL script from Jenkins.
Please see my configuration below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FnuyQ.png)

When I am running the same script from command prompt it runs but through Jenkins I am getting the following error:

```
SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.3.0 Production on Mon Sep 17 16:12:40 2018
Copyright (c) 1982, 2011, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
ERROR:
ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified

Enter user-name:
```

Do you have an idea what I am doing wrong here?

Thanks,
Raj Vardhan

Answer (score 0):

It looks like from the error you've shown that sqlplus isn't able to resolve the connection you're attempting to use in your tnsnames.ora file (DEVGEM12.ikeadt.com).

Double check that your tnsnames.ora file (usually located in `$ORACLE_HOME/network/admin`) contains a definition for this connection, something like this:

```
DEVGEM12 =
    (DESCRIPTION = 
        (ADDRESS_LIST =
            (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.1.0)(PORT = 1521))
        )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
        (SERVICE_NAME = DEVGEM12.ikeadt.com)
    )
)
```

Or alternatively you could change how you're calling sqlplus to skip using tnsnames.ora, and use [EZconnect syntax](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/EZCONNECT) like so:

```
sqlplus user/password@//hostname:port/service_name
```

Or in your case:

```
sqlplus gemini/password@devgem12.ikeadt.com/yourservicenamehere @\\ITINBAC-DWW0260\Jenkins\TEST.sql > your_log.log
```